# Exception at memory location with opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm new opencv c++ developer. I applied the SLIC superpixel so I have Mat:labels contain the ID of each pixel, I applied SPLIT on the image to get the Green channel and then I'm looking to change the value of specific pixels who have the ID=150 ( each pixel =! of 150 must is converted to black pixel). after debug I got this bug and this [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHz2a.png):

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB63A0A388 : Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000001496AFE290.
>   Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB63A0A388 : Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000001496AFE290.

Here's my code

```
   int main()
{

    Mat labels;
    Mat RGB[3], HSV[3],S_HSV,image3;
    vector<double> STD, generale_mean;
    Mat image, Red, Green, Blue, image2,mask,Gray;
    int region_number;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    image = imread("D:\\mémoire\\eye.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    //applying the superpixel 

    Ptr<cv::ximgproc::SuperpixelSLIC> slic = cv::ximgproc::createSuperpixelSLIC(image, 100,50, 0.01);
    slic->iterate(10);
    if (true)
        slic->enforceLabelConnectivity(50);

    slic->getLabelContourMask(mask, true);
    image.setTo((0, 0, 255), mask);
    slic->getLabels(labels);
    region_number = slic->getNumberOfSuperpixels();

    cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB);

    cv::cvtColor(image, Gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    split(image, RGB);

    Red.push_back(RGB[0]);
    Green.push_back(RGB[1]);
    Blue.push_back(RGB[2]);

        int f = 150;
        Mat Green1 = Green.clone();
        int Y =0;

        for (int j = 0; j < Green1.rows; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Green1.cols; i++) {

                double N = labels.at<double>(Point(i, j));
                if (N =! f) 

                    Green1.at<double>(Point(i, j)) = 00000;

            }
        }

        cv::imshow("green", Green1);        

    waitKey(0);         // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this? This is not enough for us to help you more than this.

Comment: i'll update my post and put all the code

Comment: What is the exception that was thrown? The error message basically just says that OpenCV threw an exception, but it does not show the details of the opencv exception. For example, a call stack would really help.

Comment: how can i show the exception ?!

Comment: The error is in this line `Green1.at<double>(Point(i, j)) = 00000;`  first is an uchar not a double, and you can do without point like this `Green1.at<uchar>(j,i) = 0;` note that at receives row, column in comparison of point that receives x,y

Comment: also by the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/da9/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1SuperpixelSLIC.html#aca4e1b5813a6c16635700c85b9f13c23), ` slic->getLabels(labels);` gives a type 32S image, that means int, therfore `double N = labels.at<double>(Point(i, j));` should be `int N = labels.at<int>(j,i);

Comment: i can't belive @api55 it work thanks a lot you saved my day

Comment: @benmbarekManef I will write it as answer with a little bit more details, so that you can understand the problem :)

Comment: @api55 you salved the problem don't need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with the types of the image. When you load an image in OpenCV using:

```
image = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

it will be an image of type CV8UC3. This means, that it will have 3 channels (the C3 part) and that each pixel value for each channel is of type unsigned int of 8 bits. In C++ you can use uchar for it. Then when you use the at function, you need to use a type that can hold the information correctly... that is in this case uchar. In you code you have:

```
Green1.at<double>(Point(i, j)) = 00000;
```

which should be:

```
Green1.at<uchar>(j,i) = 0;
```

Note that also `Point(i,j)` is not needed and can be replaced by `j,i`.

The `.at<type>(row, column)` function is more or less equivalent to do:

```
Mat test;
type* data = reinterpret_cast<type*>(test.data);
data[row][column];
```

---

You also have a problem in:

```
double N = labels.at<double>(Point(i, j));
```

but labels it is assign by

```
slic->getLabels(labels);
```

which gives a mat of type CV_32SC1 -> that means, 1 Channel and 32 bits signed integer, or in C++, int.

Then this should be :

```
int N = labels.at<int>(j,i);
```

---

Finally:

this

```
Red.push_back(RGB[0]);
Green.push_back(RGB[1]);
Blue.push_back(RGB[2]);
```

should be:

```
Red = RGB[0];
Green = RGB[1];
Blue = RGB[2];
```